# Read 2 int and \n with fscanf - thoughts?

Tags: c, scanf

In my current project for C language, I have to read from a file 2 int and make sure that after those there is a newline.
I'm trying to use the fscanf function (fscanf(f,"%d %d",&a,&b)), but this way I don't know if these are in the same line or if there is a newline after.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets()` to read a whole line into a buffer, then inspect the line you read, perhaps by using `sscanf()` to parse out two integers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. 
I just found another way that might work (I thought I already tried it without success, but now it seems to be working just fine) 

fscanf(f, "%d %d %[^\n]", &a1, &a2);

Thanks again!

Comment: @user1428534 No, that really doesn't work, where do you expect the final `%` to store its results? You're invoking undefined behavior, really bad code.